# Increasing limit of sets is in union of families

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$ be a sequence of sets such that $A_i \in \cal{F}_i$, where $\cal{F}_i \supseteq \cal{F}_{i-1} \forall i$

Let $A = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} {A_i}, \cal{F} = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} {\cal{F}_i}$

How can I say that $A \in \cal{F}$?  This seems true, but I'm not able to get the argument.

Edit: Not true.  See comment below.

Comment: This is not true.  Let $A_i = [i]$, $\cal{F}_i$ be the collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which are of cardinality $\leq i$, then $A = \mathbb{N}$ but $\cal{F}$ is the collection of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.